# Why is there so little support in Windows 8 store apps for line of business / data based applications?

Tags: database, windows-store-apps

So basically there is no EF or ADO.NET for windows store apps. Please correct me if i am wrong but all my research has shown that one needs to either use XML or sqlite. I have not used sqlite at all so maybe i just need to research that some more.

I am very comfortable working with EF and dont understand why microsoft would not allow technologies that they have spent years developing to be excluded from the windows store apps.
Does anyone know the main reason behind this decision? A lot of users are saying "Ah but you can just host your data" and actually no we cannot . The terms and agreements to every cloud system i have viewed cannot be used in our organization. Besides we have box's which are only connected to the internet for a time period only to sync data. So it basically pulls data into the local db and then disconnects. The user can then carry on working on the system and will only reconnect for an upload or download sync.

so Basically i just want to know why microsoft has sharfted some of its core data technologies with a replace of xml 0.o or sqlite

We might just go full WPF as a desktop app but this is not ideal. The "metro" apps are very user friendly and we can get new staff working on the system very quickly